# How can I save an XML in a path with 260+ characters?

Tags: powershell, robocopy, copy-item

Here is my situation.  I have an XML that resides in a path that contains 260+ characters.  One of the folders in this path will always be random, another one is based on versions so it could be different as well.

I am trying to load the XML, make changes to it, and save it back.  So far I haven't been able to do that in place so I am copying it to C:\Windows\Temp, making the changes there, and then trying to copy it back in place, which has worked in manual tests.

My main problem is the file path contains more than 260+ characters so Copy-Item hasn't worked properly and I haven't been able to figure out how to get Robocopy to work since I have to use a variable for the path because of the random folders.

XML modification works, copying out to Temp works, the problem I am having is copying it back to the 260+ character path.

I am very new to Powershell as an FYI.  Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
$folderLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ProgramA\ -Filter userConfig.xml -Recurse | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
    Select-Object -last 1 | 
    Select-Object Directory | 
    Format-Table -hide

foreach ($f in $folderLocation){
    Copy-Item userConfig.xml C:\Windows\Temp
}


$myXML = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$myXML.Load("C:\Windows\Temp\userConfig.xml")

$isActive = $myXML.SelectSingleNode("//setting[@name = 'Active']")
$isActive.value = "True"

$myXML.Save("C:\Windows\Temp\userConfig.xml")

$convertFolder = [System.String]$folderLocation

Copy-Item ("C:\Windows\Temp\userConfig.xml") $convertFolder
```

Here is the Robocopy code I tried, I know it's a hackjob but I tried to imitate some things I saw online:

```
function copy-stuff
{
param([string]$source = "C:\Windows\Temp",
[string]$destination = $convertFolder,
[string]$options = “/R:0″,”/W:0″,”/COPY:DAT”)
[string]$file = "userConfig.xml"

robocopy $source $destination $file $options

}
```

I tried a couple different things with robocopy but this is what I still had saved.  I haven't studied up on creating and using functions in Powershell so this was a monkey see monkey do attempt.

Comment: try using robocopy.exe to copy the file.

Comment: Temporary substitute the folder that has a long file path with a drive letter and use that drive in your script. http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html

Comment: Robocopy will work. It's one of the only things I could find that I could get to work on extra-long paths. Post the Robocopy code you tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: There you go @Entbark, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the Robocopy part of your code:

It looks like you aren't passing anything to your function, but are relying on default values. Try this:

```
function Copy-Stuff {
    param (
        [string]$source,
        [string]$destination,
        [string]$file
    )

    robocopy $source $destination $file /R:0 /W:0 /COPY:DAT
}

$convertFolder = "blahblah"
Copy-Stuff -Source "C:\Windows\Temp" -Destination $convertFolder -File "userConfig.xml"
```

If the options never change, then don't bother making them a variable.

Comment: The only place it seems to be choking now is accepting the $convertFolder variable as a -Destination parameter.  $convertFolder is $folderLocation converted to string.  Due to the 2 random folders in the path of $folderLocation I wasn't sure how else to pass that to the function other than a variable.

Comment: You're trying to convert an array of objects (even if it is just one object) to a string. You will need to iterate through the array to access each path.

Comment: Basically, `$convertFolder = [System.String]$folderLocation` should be in your `foreach` loop.